# how to save form into array and show them in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

hi at first im sry for my bad english.
im totally new at angularjs i wanna make a form then save form to an array and show array in my html.
my question is how save form in array and keep them always , and then show them ?

here is my jsfidle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/12098/
here my js codes:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm",
    })
    .when("/new", {
        templateUrl : "new.html",
        controller : "newController"
    })
    .when("/view", {
        templateUrl : "view.html",
        controller : "viewController"
    });
});
app.controller("newController", ['myfactory',

 function ($scope,myfactory) {
    $scope.master = {};

    $scope.update = function(user) {
      $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
    };

    $scope.reset = function(form) {
     if (form) {
        form.$setPristine();
        form.$setUntouched();
     }
     $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
   };
 
   $scope.alluser = [{
    name: "",
    family: "",
    code: "",
    birth: "",
    father: "",
    explain: ""
   }];
    $scope.addItem = function(user) {
      $scope.alluser.name.push(user.name);
      $scope.alluser.family.push(user.family);
      $scope.alluser.code.push(user.code);
      $scope.alluser.birth.push(user.birth);
      $scope.alluser.father.push(user.father);
      $scope.alluser.explain.push(user.explain);
    };


}]);
app.controller("viewController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "I love Paris";
});

app.factory('myfactory', function() {
    return {
        array: function() {
            return $scope.alluser;
        }
    };
});
```

and this is my html form and my index.html :

```html
<br /><br />
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="newController">

<form>
name : <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /><br />
family : <input type="text" ng-model="user.family" /><br />
code melli : <input type="text" ng-model="user.code" /><br />
birth: <input type="text" ng-model="user.birth" /><br />
father: <input type="text" ng-model="user.father" /><br />
explain : <input type="text" ng-model="user.explain" /><br />
<input type="submit" ng-click="addItem(master)" value="Save" />


    <ul>
        <li ng-show="user.name">{{user.name}}</li>
        <li ng-show="user.family">{{user.family}}</li>
        <li ng-show="user.code">{{user.code}}</li>
        <li ng-show="user.birth">{{user.birth}}</li>
        <li ng-show="user.father">{{user.father}}</li>
        <li ng-show="user.explain">{{user.explain}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-controller="newController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in alluser"><a href="#">{{user.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


</form>


</div>
```

Comment: there are quite a bit of errors i can see. Can you create a plunker of fiddle for your question. That way it will be easy to debug.

Comment: @AlexRumbaNicked jsfiddle added bro

Comment: u see bro, you have declared templates with the names but you haven't made the page. use of controller is redundant as well and many more. I will try to replicate it in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) . But, it is just too much work for me for 15 points :/

Comment: check out the plunker in my answer @james, if that is enough do mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had defined routes but there were no templates present in your fiddle. You had not declared the whole app as well. Furthermore, you have not injected scope as well. I have removed the unwanted components and created a plunker for you.

**PLUNKER:**[Code Revision](http://plnkr.co/edit/2bOuHKT49Ghteg3dw0iI?p=preview)

**HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
   <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-beta.16" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.16" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
<body ng-controller="newController">

<form method="POST" name="user">
name : <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /><br />
family : <input type="text" ng-model="user.family" /><br />
code melli : <input type="text" ng-model="user.code" /><br />
birth: <input type="text" ng-model="user.birth" /><br />
father: <input type="text" ng-model="user.father" /><br />
explain : <input type="text" ng-model="user.explain" /><br />
<input type="submit" ng-click="addItem(user)" value="Save" />

    <ul>
        <li ng-show="user.name">{{user.name}}</li>
        <li ng-show="user.family">{{user.family}}</li>
        <li ng-show="user.code">{{user.code}}</li>
        <li ng-show="user.birth">{{user.birth}}</li>
        <li ng-show="user.father">{{user.father}}</li>
        <li ng-show="user.explain">{{user.explain}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div >

        <p ng-repeat="x in alluser"> {{ x }} </p>

    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("newController", ['$scope','myfactory',
 function ($scope,myfactory) {
    $scope.master = {};

    $scope.update = function(user) {
      $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
    };

    $scope.reset = function(form) {
     if (form) {
        form.$setPristine();
        form.$setUntouched();
     }
     $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
   };

   $scope.alluser = [{
    name: "",
    family: "",
    code: "",
    birth: "",
    father: "",
    explain: ""
   }];
    $scope.addItem = function(user) {
      $scope.alluser.push(user);
    };


}]);

app.factory('myfactory', function() {
    return {
        array: function() {
            return $scope.alluser;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: tnx dude its very helpful :X

Answer (score 1):

Update addItem function like below.

```
$scope.addItem = function(user) {
  $scope.alluser.push(user);
};
```

Remove ng-controller from second div.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in alluser"><a href="#">{{user.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ng-controller  on the div,

```
 <div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in alluser"><a href="#">{{user.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: tnx but nothing changed